# How to make function2 run after function1 has already finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I am working on a sidebar navigation: And the sidebar opens when we click on the toggle button and it stays open until we click again on the toggle button. 
For the same sidebar I have a hover function : on mouseEnter sidebar opens and onMouseLeave sidebar closes.

The problem I have is with the closing the sidebar onClick. When I click close on the toggle button the sidebar stays open because the mouseEnter function is triggered.

I want the mouseEnter to be ready after the navbar close animation is finished.

Here is my code for the click event:

```
$('body').on('click', '.sidebar-toggler', function (e) {
            var sidebar = $('.page-sidebar');
            var sidebarMenu = $('.page-sidebar-menu');
        if (body.hasClass("page-sidebar-closed")) {
                    body.removeClass("page-sidebar-closed");
                    sidebarMenu.removeClass("page-sidebar-menu-closed");
                } else {
                    body.addClass("page-sidebar-closed");
                    sidebarMenu.addClass("page-sidebar-menu-closed");
                    if (body.hasClass("page-sidebar-fixed")) {
                        sidebarMenu.trigger("mouseleave");
                    }
    }
```

and here is the code for the hover event:

```
 if (body.hasClass('page-sidebar-fixed')) {
            $('.page-sidebar').on('mouseenter', function () {
                if (body.hasClass('page-sidebar-closed')) {
                    $(this).find('.page-sidebar-menu').removeClass('page-sidebar-menu-closed');
                }
            }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                if (body.hasClass('page-sidebar-closed')) {
                    $(this).find('.page-sidebar-menu').addClass('page-sidebar-menu-closed');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why you need click and mouseenter events for the same? When you click in toggle button, sidebar appears... so the question is why you need the mouseenter to open sidebar?

Comment: Why not? The hovering is made just to take a peak at the menu and on mouseLeave it closes while the click event keep the menu opened

Comment: I think that with the click event and the mouseLeave event is suficient, because I don't know how is the purpose of mouseenter, but if it's your specification I can't do anything about it. Try with `off()` as juallom said in his answer, but with that you need to `off` and `on` dinamically the events and it's a hard task to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to .off() the mouseenter event when the sidebar is opened with the toggle button.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: I will check it now. Thanks